# Connect Android Device to a localhost on Windows

Tags: android, windows, localhost

I tried to connect to a localhost on my windows PC from Android devices but it doesn't work at all.
I host it using ISS Express (installed with VS2013)

I tried `http://10.0.2.2:59087` and my ip `http://192.168.43.83:59087`

I connected them using an AP from my Android and from the router

I also disabled windows firewall

All this configurations but nothing is changed

What is the problem?!!!

Answer (score 0):

you HAVE to be in the same network for this to work, that's all, you don't have to go through all that trouble, if you are in the same network, then you can access your ip easily just make sure your windows side server (eg: localhost:8080) is active and accessible

Comment: That is, PC and Android connect to the same router; and the website I host is running(tested it from the PC itself)!

Comment: open the browser in your phone, and try to reach your PC ip adress